# Rails - simple form - boolean attribute not accepting false/no radio button choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am making a rails app using simple form (with bootstrap).

I have this question in my form:

```
<%= f.input :ethics, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Is an ethics review relevant?' %>
```

The ethics attribute is a boolean in my table.

The form renders with radio buttons for yes/no.

The default shows as no - but if that's the answer I want to give I'm stuck because I can't submit the form. I get an error that says an answer is required.

Why doesn't simple form acknowledge false as a boolean answer?

The log shows:

```
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "project"=>{"title"=>"asdfsdf ", "byline"=>"", "description"=>"asdfsdf ", "problem"=>"", "solution"=>"", "remark"=>"",  "ethics"=>"false",
```

Comment: Can you paste Rails server log that you see when submit the form?

Comment: Add the full log, from request to response.

Comment: Also the error message *an answer is required*, but I don't see any such field in the log. Do you have model called Answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably just forgot to add the `ethics` field to the list of permitted attributes in your controller.

```
params.require(:project).permit(..., :ethics)
```

You should also have no `presence` validation in the model. Because `false` is false and will return false for the validation.

Use

```
validates :ethics, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ] }
```

Comment: I was trying to know from OP that you guessed to ensure myself. But OP didn't provide further log -_-

Comment: No - it's there. I don't get an error if I choose the yes radio button.

Comment: @Mel What DBMS you are using?

Comment: Do you have a validation in the model for that field? Which validation? Can you show us?

Comment: There is a validation in the model for presence. I don't know what DMBS means.

Comment: @Mel Postgresql, MySQL etc which one you have?